# Subtracting Date-time objects in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, type-conversion

I have two columns in my dataframe with datetime64[ns] values. I would like to subtract the end-date from my start-date and place that value of a new column? How do I do that?

Here is an example of my data:

**StartedDate(Column1)**

2018-09-02 02:54:39

2018-09-02 15:14:31

2018-09-02 18:04:35

2018-09-02 18:04:35

**EndedDate(column 2)**

208-09-02 15:20:15

2018-09-02 18:04:34

2018-09-02 18:11:15

2018-09-02 18:39:34

In excel it converts the dates in numbers (e.g. 43789,04). I want to do the same with these values and convert them into these kinds of numbers and then subtract them. However, I find it difficult to do that in Python.

The output I am currently getting has the format of (12:25:36) while I want it to be like that (43740.64-43740.12= 0.52)

Comment: No it does not answer my question. I have to deal with time in my case.

Comment: Sorry, but I think my example is pretty clear? Which part don't you understand? I have two dates in the format I specified and I have also included the desired output I want. Please tell me if something is wrong with my question

Comment: Correct, the output I get is for example (12:25:36) while I want it to be: 43740,64 - 43740,12 = 0,52

Comment: Sorry, I close it wrongly. Now understand what need.

Comment: Jezrael a last thing, what if I want to convert StartedDate to an integer e.g. (43740). How do I do it? I want to convert it to this format and then keep only the integer part. I dont think there is a point in making a separate question now that you have helped me so far.

Comment: You can check  my first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59137309/1) -  and change `return float(delta.days) + (float(delta.seconds) / 86400)` to `return float(delta.days)`

Comment: This is the error I get back: KeyError: Timestamp('2019-10-02 02:54:39')

Comment: Last row should be `df['startedAt'] = df['startedAt'].apply(excel_date)`

Comment: I still have a function which returns the value you said and I have a for loop to create a new column with the value I receive But I get this error

Comment: hmmm, what is reason for loop? Only use `df['startedAt'] = df['startedAt'].apply(excel_date) `

Comment: I fixed that, but the issue seems to be at another line : value = df[i]['startedAt']

Comment: Okay i will work on it, thank you!

Comment: When I do df['startedAt'] = df['startedAt'].apply(excel_date), this issue appears: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: fixed it dont worry about it

Comment: A small question @jezrael if you have some time. I am applying the function that returns:     return int(delta.days).  And I have a small issue. In my code afterwards I have the following: df['endedAtDecimals'] = df['endedAt'].apply(excel_date). However, I have some values which are empty. They have 'NaN. And it shows the following error: cannot convert float NaN to integer
In other words it cannot convert it to an integer because of NaN

Comment: Is possible use `float(delta.days)` ? By default is not possible convert NaN to integers, need [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Dan mentioned in comments is not necessary add starting datetimes, because subtracting.

So convert timedeltas with [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and add [`Series.dt.seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html) divided by `86400`:

```
df['StartedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartedDate'])
df['EndedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndedDate'])

delta = df['EndedDate'] - df['StartedDate']
df['diff'] = delta.dt.days.astype(float) + (delta.dt.seconds.astype(float) / 86400)
print (df)
          StartedDate           EndedDate      diff
0 2018-09-02 02:54:39 2018-09-02 15:20:15  0.517778
1 2018-09-02 15:14:31 2018-09-02 18:04:34  0.118090
2 2018-09-02 18:04:35 2018-09-02 18:11:15  0.004630
3 2018-09-02 18:04:35 2018-09-02 18:39:34  0.024294
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your responses! I have one small issue now. The following issue occurs: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: @Vasilis - Can you checnge `dt.datetime` to `datetime.datetime` ?

Comment: Why convert to the Excel datenum, you cancel out the `dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)` in the subtraction. Doesn't this question boil down to "how do I find the difference of two datestimes in units of days (including decimal fractions)"?

Comment: I did convert it to datetime.datetime and this pops up: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: I am trying to figure it out Dan myself as well. Do you have any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: @Dan - thank you, you are absolutley right, it is much better and faster.

Comment: A last comment, I now get 0.0 for all of them. Why is that?

Comment: @Vasilis - Hard question, maybe help `df['StartedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartedDate'])
    df['EndedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndedDate'])` before my solution

Comment: @Vasilis - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Comment: Jezrael a last thing, what if I want to convert StartedDate to an integer e.g. (43740). How do I do it? I want to convert it to this format and then keep only the integer part. I dont think there is a point in making a separate question now that you have helped me so far.